# the best way to add an anchor with image and text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an HTML anchor that includes an image with a visible text legend on top. My code is:

```
<li class="grelha lin2 col4">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="img/imagem.gif" alt="Proj">
    <p class="leg normal">Proj</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

The CSS is:

```
.leg {
    width: 112px;
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 23px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    user-select: none;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.nav {
    color: #ccc;
}

.normal {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    color: black;
}
```

Visually everything works great, but the link continues to be detected below the `li` box that is 120x120px. But nothing is there visually.

The question is: how to achieve the same result that function well in SEO, and allow me to have this boxes close to another working with the right link.

Comment: can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: What's the problem, and the desired result specifically?  "The same result thta functions well in SEO"?  Also, it's technically incorrect to have a <p> (block level element) contained within an <a> (inline element)

Comment: Regarding the alt attribute, the markup you're using isn't particularly good for non-graphical User Agents (bots, screen readers, Lynx) because the alt text is an exact duplicate of the surrounding text.  An empty attribute (`alt=""`) is preferred over redundant text if you're providing a descriptive caption as well.

Comment: I think I already discover how to achieve what I want, although I have duplicate markup:

I changed the HTML this way:

    <li class="grelha lin4 col1">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/imagem.gif" alt="Proj">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="leg normal">Proj</a>
    </li>

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xpTDZ/

Comment: Have you thought of using CSS `background-image`?

Comment: Listen to @cale_b, you cannot have block level elements in an anchor tag. Bad HTML mojo.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<span>` makes more sense here, as it is an inline element rather than `<p>` which is a block element

```
<li class="grelha lin4 col1"> 
     <a href="#"> 
         <img src="img/imagem.gif" alt="Proj"> 
         <span>Proj</span>
     </a> 
</li>​
```

and than use css to style it the way you want